# Does Accelerating to Double the Speed Require Quadruple the Fuel Consumption, or Double the Fuel Consumption?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, work, friction

I'm writing a piece on the efficiency of trains versus trucks, and one of the points I was making is that trains can take advantage of not having to stop and start multiple times. This is obviously beneficial, although probably negligible for highways vs cross-country trips when compared to rolling/wind resistance. But it made me think of something else that I can't get out of my head. If an object, let's say a train, is traveling twice as fast, did it require four times as much chemical energy, from fuel, to be used?

The actual numbers are irrelevant, but imagine two fully loaded trains of equal design and weight, let's say ten million kilograms. They both start from stop, but train A accelerates to 100 kmph, while train B accelerates to 200 kmph. Train B now has four times the kinetic energy, so did it burn four times the fuel? If force is mass*acceleration, and the force is generated by combustion, then it seems all we need to burn is the same rate of fuel, but for twice as long. Working backwards from momentum we see that we only needed twice the fuel, but working backwards from kinetic energy we need four times the fuel.

This same principle applies for every method of transportation. Two rockets ships of equal weight lead to the same confusing answer provided one of them applies the same thrust, and the same fuel burn rate, for simply twice as long. We have consumed twice the chemical energy, yet have four times the kinetic energy. Acceleration by propeller is no different.

In these examples I assumed no rolling/wind resistance in order to make things more clear. Obviously in real life we have quadratic wind/rolling resistance to overcome. But I'm still curious.

To make a long story short, does accelerating to twice the speed require four times the fuel, or twice the fuel?

I looked back through my physics 12 high school curriculum and couldn't find the answer. Then I sat down with some extended family, including an engineer, and asked them. No one could answer the question and we were all stumped, thinking that we must be missing something obvious.

Comment: The conservation of mechanical energy implies that work equals the change in kinetic energy (I am assuming there is no potential energy and I am ignoring friction etc.).  Work is force times distance.  If a force is applied for a fixed time and the vehicle is traveling faster it is applied over a longer distance and more work is done.  Is this what you are missing?

Comment: Have you drawn any conclusions?

Comment: Can't say that I have, KDP.

Comment: @TimothyCoish that is too bad since I gave you the answer more than a year ago. As long as you look at all of the relevant conservation laws you can determine when you need more energy and when you don’t

Answer (score 0):

> To make a long story short, does accelerating to twice the speed require four times the fuel, or twice the fuel?

It depends.

A force on the vehicle implies an interaction with something else. A train pushes against the tracks, a car pushes against the road, a propeller pushes against the fluid, a rocket pushes against the exhaust. You must consider that thing as well. Both momentum and energy are conserved, but only when you consider both the vehicle and the thing it pushes against.

So, suppose that an engine provides work $W$ while accelerating a vehicle of mass $m$ from $v_i$ to $v_f$ by pushing against something of mass $M$ which accelerates from $V_i$ to $V_f$.

Conservation of momentum gives $$m v_i+M V_i=m v_f+M V_f$$

Conservation of energy gives $$\frac{1}{2}m v_i^2 + \frac{1}{2}M V_i^2 + W=\frac{1}{2}m v_f^2 + \frac{1}{2}M V_f^2$$

These two equations assume that the “push” mass has one velocity at the end and that the mass of the vehicle is constant. Things like rockets violate both of those conditions, so it would just be an approximation. However, you can make an “instantaneous” version of these that is accurate for rockets too. But for this question we will just approximate the rocket using these equations.

For the car $v_i=V_i=0$ and then we can eliminate $V_f$ and solve for $W$ to get $$W=\frac{(m+M)}{2M}m v_f^2 \approx \frac{1}{2}m v_f^2$$ where the approximation is in the limit where $M$ is much larger than $m$. Here, doubling $v_f$ quadruples $W$.

For the rocket if we start with the rocket at rest then again $v_i=V_i=0$ and $V_f=-V_e$ where $V_e$ is the exhaust velocity of the rocket engine. Then we can eliminate $M$ and solve for $W$ to get $$W=\frac{1}{2} m v_f (V_e+v_f) \approx \frac{1}{2} m v_f V_e$$ where the approximation is in the limit where $V_e$ is much larger than $v_f$. Here doubling $v_f$ doubles $W$

> we were all stumped, thinking that we must be missing something obvious.

Usually people miss conservation of momentum. You didn’t seem to miss momentum, but perhaps you neglected that it is conserved. Or perhaps you neglected the energy that goes into the thing the vehicle pushes against

Comment: Initially we thought that conservation of momentum was the answer, but the problem is that doesn't seem to make much sense in the context of the Earth. As we add more and more force to the Earth we make it rotate faster and faster, but this simply means it has more kinetic energy, and doesn't makes sense, seeing that it would be reducing its kinetic energy or increasing depending on which way you were accelerating it, East, or West.

Comment: It works for the earth just fine. If you want to consider the rotation then you would simply add conservation of angular momentum also. Conservation of energy and conservation of linear momentum still apply

Answer (score 0):

Work done (which is a measure of energy input) has the formula $(F \ d)$ where F is force and d is the displacement or distance travelled. Distance travelled in time t with acceleration a is $d = 1/2 a t^2$. Putting the two together we have: $$ E = (F \ a t^2)/2 \ .$$

If train A accelerates for time t=1 and B accelerates for t = 2, then all else being equal, the result is B uses 4 times as much energy, in agreement with the kinetic energy calculation.

The terminal velocity reached is given by $v = at$ and it easy to see that that the train B reaches twice the velocity of train A if they have the same acceleration, confirming your statement.

The key thing to note is if we use the equation for distance $( d = 1/2 a t^2)$ ,the distance travelled by the train with twice the acceleration time is 4 times as far as the slower accelerating train and we would expect the train that travels 4 times as far to use 4 times as much energy.

It is also interesting to note that a train requires 4 times as much fuel to accelerate from 200 to 201 mph, than to accelerate from 100 to 101 mph, even though the acceleration and force is the same in both cases. At the higher speed the engine had to inject 4 times as much fuel to gain that extra one mph. This is why drag cars measure fuel consumption in gallons per mile instead of miles per gallon.

Momentum $(m v)$ is not a quantity with units of energy. It is a separate, but related concept.

> To make a long story short, does accelerating to twice the speed
> require four times the fuel, or twice the fuel?

Short answer: It requires 4 times the energy or fuel input.

Here are some other things to consider. Air resistance at high speeds is roughly proportional to $-k v^2$, where k is friction constant for air. Once the trains reach their final velocity, the faster train will require 4 times as much energy per unit time, per unit distance, to maintain its velocity, compared to the slower train over long distances.

> I'm writing a piece on the efficiency of trains versus trucks, and one
> of the points I was making is that trains can take advantage of not
> having to stop and start multiple times. This is obviously beneficial,
> although probably negligible for highways vs cross-country trips when
> compared to rolling/wind resistance.

When comparing trains to trucks, another important thing to consider is that the train carriages are close coupled and all except the tractor unit at the front are shielded from the air resistance by the carriage in front. If there are 100 carriages in the train and the frontal area of the tractor unit is 'A' then the air resistance is basically proportional to A with a bit extra for skin friction on the sides of the trains. The trucks on the other hand have to maintain larger gaps between themselves for safety reasons and do not gain so much from slip streaming and so the air resistance on the trucks is approximately 100 A. That's a big energy saving for the train compared to the trucks, if they are transporting the same mass of goods the same distance.

The hard wheels and track of the train also experience significantly less rolling resistance than the rubber tyres of the trucks. However, trucks are required to get the goods the final mile to their individual destinations, so trains and trucks have to work together.

Comment: I am still confused, because in our spaceship example we don't know what the "true" velocity is, because we don't have any agreed upon frame of reference. For example, we could have a spaceship that accelerates away from Earth, then flips around and accelerates relative to Earth in the opposite direction. Relative to the Earth, the kinetic energy is exponentially increasing as it accelerates away, and exponentially decreasing as it accelerates towards, but the force produced by the engines through fuel burn should be independent of this. The kinetic energy and chemical energy don't match.

Comment: "Relative to the Earth, the kinetic energy is exponentially increasing as it accelerates away," Okayyy... Lets say that took time  = t seconds and is at distance = x...  " then flips around and accelerates relative to Earth in the opposite direction" So it changed its orientation and is now facing the Earth and accelerates towards the Earth, so it is in fact slowing down relative to the Earth but still moving away until it eventually comes to rest  at time = 2*t seconds and distance from Earth = 2x. Is that what you mean?

Comment: *It is also interesting to note that for a train to accelerate from 100 mph to 101 mph requires 4 times as much fuel to accelerate from 200 mph to 210 mph, even though the acceleration and force is the same in both cases.*      I think you've got some typos or need to rearrange this statement grammatically

Comment: @RC_23 Thanks for spotting that. I think I have corrected it now.